# Is it possible to hide certain corda nodes from others in the network?

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am trying to develop a corda network in which the use case requires nodes to only see a specific set of other nodes. Can a nodes 'list of peers' be defined when introducing it to the network so that it cannot make transactions with another nodes or even see the other entities in the network.

I.e. In a network of 4 nodes (A,B,C,D) can A's peers be set to be only C & D and B's peers be set to C & D, whereas C and D can see all the nodes as normal. The goal would be to hide A from B in this case (and vice versa).

Comment: Please rewrite your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding peers on a Corda Network from one another is not possible at this time. All nodes are intended to be visible with established identities.

The existence of an identity on a Corda Network does not reveal any information beyond the operation of a Cordapp by that legal entity. Transactions between parties on a network are hidden from all other parties on the network.

You can establish Business Networks which define a subset of nodes who do business together. The members of a Business Network are only able to be communicated with by other members of the same network. More information can be found here: https://solutions.corda.net/business-networks/intro.html